# jQuery Load Result form another page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i am using this way to bind ASP.NET GridView Without postback.
i want to know what are the problems of this way?
what are the alternative ways?
here is my code :

```
 <input id="btnLoadDIV" type="button" value="button" />
                  <div id="somediv">
        </div>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnLoadDIV").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                  var url;
            url = "test.aspx?type=test1";
            $("#somediv").load(url);
            });
        });
     </script>
```

Test.aspx BehindCode Code :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Request.QueryString("type") = "test1" Then
bindgrid()
End If
End Sub
```

Test.Aspx  markup code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks. regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic things you ought to be aware of:

1. The page will fully execute it's life cycle even if only part of the page is being updated.
2. Grid views have a horrible footprint and I haven't used them in a long time because of it.

Potential alternatives:

1. Use a generic handler (.ashx) for running your ajax requests.
2. If you really want to use ajax on a grid view you might want to read this: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/05/7_simple_steps_to_ajaxenable_y.html

Comment: The button and div are both above the script. "Grid views have a horrible footprint and I haven't" ? :) +1 for the other suggestions.

Comment: 'The page will fully execute it's life cycle even if only part of the page is being updated'  You Mean Test.aspx ?     'Grid views have a horrible footprint and I haven't'   what is this mean ?

Comment: in generic handler can i Bind A Grid and returning it ? thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: i prefer use jQuery instead Ajax COntrol Toolkit

Comment: @karim79, @shaahin: gotta love ADD.

Comment: @shaahin: in the generic handler, you can emit pretty much whatever code you want.  So you'd use it to emit the grid itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is fine. The only thing I would do differently is I would pass the URL's parameters as second argument to `$.load`. I just feel it is neater:

```
$("#somediv").load("test.aspx", {type: "test1"});
```

Comment: thanks. and how can i use test1 in test.aspx  ? because I'm Binding Grid in page load .